# How to keep a socket alive after script finish executing

Tags: php, facebook, sockets, fsockopen

I have written a php script, which connects to facebook chat via tcp socket. My questions are:

1. How to keep the socket alive even when the php script is ended? I want other php file to communicate with facebook XMPP server via this socket? I have tried to save the socket as a session variable, but it did not work.
2. I tried to use pfsockopen instead of socket_create, according to some forum discussion. But I always receive failure when I call pfsockopen function.

Any one has idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a standalone daemon for this.

Comment: But if you have a standalone daemon, would other scripts communicate with the daemon via IPC? Do PHP scripts run in the same memory space so that function calls can be made directly or we need an IPC?  I'm new to PHP and I find establishing a new socket to the daemon (as mentioned above) is a horrible solution?

Comment: You need some IPC for this. This can be TCP/UDP/Unix socket for example. Php daemon and webserver scripts run on separate address space. I  just can suggest smth like https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon for daemon part and `serialize` + HTTP as IPC protocol

Comment: That's what I though. I may get my daemon to write JSON ready data into the /proc FS and then the PHP web scripts, instead of taking the time to open up a socket to the deamon, it could simply read the data from the /proc and stream it back.  My guess is that reading from the /proc FS is MUCH faster than opening a socket and reading the same stream.  But I'll try and prove that theory before doing a full implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share the socket between different PHP scripts. What @seriyPS suggests makes sense - create a PHP script, that:

- never ends
- opens socket to FB chat
- Listen on another socket

Then your PHP scripts can open socket to that 'daemon' PHP script, send a message, the daemon sends it to FB and returns the FB response.

Comment: @Darhazer: In your solution, I don't really see how the problem is solved.  I'm guessing that 'stella' wants to avoid actually establishing a connection (creating a socket) for each client request.  Sure the 'daemon' may have the socket open to FB, but the PHP script still needs to connect to the deamon now (nothing solved)?  Am I missing something here?  I have a client with the same problem for which I'm investigating a solution.  Isn't there a simple way to avoid opening a socket in PHP?